# Algebraic formula manipulation - solve for $y$ in the equation $0.25=1-(\sqrt[r]{|y-v|}×s)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find $y$ in the following formula. I used an online algebraic calculator, but the answer wasn't correct (it omitted the index):

$0.25=1-(\sqrt[r]{|y-v|}×s)$

**EDIT**

The online calculator gave the following:

$y=v+\dfrac{0.5625}{s^2}$

This doesn't produce correct results, even for *r* = 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rearrange to get
$$(\textstyle\sqrt[r]{|y-v|}\times s)=1-0.25=0.75.$$
Divide by $s$ to get
$$\textstyle\sqrt[r]{|y-v|}=\dfrac{0.75}{s}=\dfrac{3}{4s}.$$
Take the $r$th power to get 
$$|y-v|=\left(\dfrac{3}{4s}\right)^r.$$
Now, if $y-v$ is non-negative, we have $|y-v|=y-v$, hence
$$y=v+\left(\dfrac{3}{4s}\right)^r,$$
and if $y-v$ is negative, we have $|y-v|=v-y$, hence
$$y=v-\left(\dfrac{3}{4s}\right)^r.$$
Thus,
$$y=v\pm \left(\dfrac{3}{4s}\right)^r$$
and whether the $\pm$ is a $+$ or $-$ depends on the sign of $y-v$. Also, note that this equation doesn't make sense for $s=0$.

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thank you.

Comment: @IanC: No problem, glad to help. Also, note that it agrees with the online calculator for $r=2$:
$$y=v+\left(\frac{3}{4s}\right)^2=v+\frac{3^2}{4^2\times s^2}=v+\frac{9}{16s^2}=v+\frac{0.5625}{s^2}$$
Perhaps you were using values of $v$ where $y-v$ was negative?

Comment: I'm not sure what I am doing wrong, because I'm not getting the expected results. I'll figure it out shortly :)

Comment: I checked: $y-v$ is positive.

Comment: All sorted! Thanks again @Zev